# How to search and view data in same form

Tags: mysql, vb.net, search, button, view

**Can someone give me me an example of coding for search button?**

I want the coding for button search that view the data in the same form.

I am using Visual Basic and also `Xammp` as the database, but my system was not an online system, so I think the coding is a bit different.

 Please help me!!

There are 2 different class...

1) database.vb

> ```
> Public Function searchData(ByRef sData As String)
>     Try
>         conn.Open()
>         cmd.Connection = conn
>         cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblforms WHERE Name = '" + sData + "' "
>         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
>         conn.Close()
>         MessageBox.Show("Data was found!!")
>     Catch ex As Exception
>         MessageBox.Show("Problems!! Data was not unavailable!!!")
>     End Try
> End Function
> ```

2) forms.vb

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click

    Dim search As String = txtboxSearch.Text
    databaseConn.searchData(search)

End Sub
```

**I was able to execute the command in database.vb, but I was unable to view the data at forms.vb.**

Comment: did you post the data to a control like a datagridview?

Comment: @Plutonix no, the data will be post to a textbox. there will be 4 textbox (name, address, contact no and fax no) and  a label (refno)

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some problems and going over them will be tedious. 
But one thing is right in the eye - if you want to post data to text box, here where you have

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

You need to have

```
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Then you will be able to fill text box

```
if (reader.Read()) txtBox.Text = reader[0].ToString();
```

This is for one record. Sounds like you need master-detail design with search being separate form, based on master-detail contents. But this is not a question, this is a design and well outside of scope of what we do here. If you sure that you will always retrieve a single record, you can indeed place text boxes on your form and even use them for both, search and view. For example, you type into text boxes `name` and `zip` - your code can generate dynamic SQL on btn_click:

```
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder("select * from person");
bool addWhere = false;

if(!string.IsnullOrEmpty(txtName.Text.Trim()))  
{
    if(!adWhere) sql.Append(" Where");
    addWhere = true;
    sql.Append(" name='" + txtName.Text.Trim() + "'") ;
}

if(!string.IsnullOrEmpty(txtZip.Text.Trim()))  
{
    if(!adWhere) sql.Append(" Where");
    addWhere = true;
    sql.Append(" zip='" + txtZip.Text.Trim() + "'") ;
}
```

But again, this is not the greatest idea because searches have tendency to produce multiple records.
This is just an example. I would say, go ahead with the grid and record detail. Search fills grid, grid click fills details.

TIP: Look for use of `using` as in

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(....))
{
....
}
```